# Error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime while converting to date format in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

Here is the date time format i'm trying to format.I'm getting this date format from twitter apis

```
string date = "Thu Jul 18 17:39:53 +0000 2013"
```

i tried

```
Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

But it says `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: Try `DateTime.TryParseExact`? I guess the it's wrong in `Thu` or `Jul` or `both`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dtStr, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

`ParseExact` and `TryParseExact` allows to use a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). `ddd` is the abbreviated day name, `MMM` the abbreviated month name, `dd` the day number, `HH` hours in 24h clock format, `mm` minutes, `ss` seconds, `zzzz` the [time-zone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.90).aspx#zzzSpecifier) and `yyyy` the years.

I have used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to specify that the current culture is not used but `InvariantCulture` which is similar to `"en-US"`.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/B7NWUe)</kbd>

> works but after getting date from your line of code i tried to do
>   date.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") but get the string as 12-12-2013, no
>   slashes

`/` is a replacement character for your current culture's date-separator which is obviously `-`. So also use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to specify that the separator should be used without using your current culture:

```
string result = dateTime.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: [**The "/" Custom Format Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#dateSeparator)

Comment: dat works but after getting date from your line of code i tried to do date.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") but get the string as 12-12-2013, no slashes y??

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  DateTime.ParseExact(YourDate, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss KKKK yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Its better to use Invariant culture than Current culture

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert a non-standard format, so use this:

```
string dateStr = "Thu Jul 18 17:39:53 +0000 2013";
DateTime date =  DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "ddd MMM dd h:mm:ss KKKK yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or build the correct format for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Your date string needs to be this:

```
Thu Jul 18 2013 17:39:53 +0000
```

Whatever is producing your string needs to have the year value after the month and day and before the time, like above.

```
string date = "Thu Jul 18 2013 17:39:53 +0000";
var theDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Note: This will produce a valid .NET `DateTime` object.

UPDATE:

If you cannot change the string produced, then use the `ParseExact` method with a custom format, like this:

```
string date = "Thu Jul 18 17:39:53 +0000 2013";
var theDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd H:mm:ss zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: i'm getting this from twitter apis. So i believe it would be correct

Comment: See `UPDATE:` in answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about like;

```
string date = "Thu Jul 18 17:39:53 +0000 2013";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss KKKK yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Output will be;

```
18.07.2013 20:39:53
```

[`K`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#KSpecifier) for time zone information in here.

Check out for more information;

- *[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)*

Answer (score 0):

Try using DateTime.ParseExact.

```
  string date = "Thu Jul 18 17:39:53 +0000 2013" 
  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

this.Text="22/11/2009";

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);