# Convert a string Date to the DateTime Format?

Tags: c#, string, datetime-format, string-conversion

I have very well researched all the question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567427/error-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-while-converting-to-date-f) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx). However, no matter what I try I still get the Format exception:

```
string DatePaid="9/5/2012";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(DatePaid, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

Since you changed the date string your question to `"9/5/2012"` now it could be `Day/Month/Year` or `Month/Day/Year`, Assuming that it is `Day/Month/Year`, You are getting the exception because of using `dd` since that requires day part to be in double digits. So in your string the day `9` should be `09`.

You can use single `d` and `M` which would work for both single and double digit day and month part respectively.

So your code should be:

```
string DatePaid = "9/5/2012";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(DatePaid, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Old Answer

---

You are getting the format exception because your format is wrong. Your format should be `"M/dd/yyyy"` or if you have single digit day part then use `d` which would parse both single and double digit day part.

```
string DatePaid = "9/15/2012";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(DatePaid, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your MM (month) would be equal to 15. There are only 12 months in the year not 15.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
      string DatePaid="9/15/2012";

 var date = DateTime.ParseExact(DatePaid, "M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```